# How to create Zip files in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET 2.0, we need to take multiple folders along with their files. Our requirement is to take all the folders and need to create a single zip file. Could anybody can help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a library that can make zip files. SharpZipLib, Ionic.Zip, etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx), it's one of the more popular zip libraries
2. Add a reference to ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll

You can go through the code samples when you download SharpZipLib to get a feel of how you can zip and unzip files, here's an example:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZipFiles("D:\\SharpZip","D:\\Zipped.zip");
    }

    private static void ZipFiles(string inputDirectory, string outputDirectory)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(inputDirectory))
        {
            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(inputDirectory);

            using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(outputDirectory)))
            {
                zipStream.SetLevel(9);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                foreach (string file in filenames)
                {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
                    entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        int sourceBytes;
                        do
                        {
                            sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                        } while (sourceBytes > 0);
                    }
                }
                zipStream.Finish();
                zipStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) - it's really flexible and performance is more than adequate for a production environment.

[Scott Mitchell has a great example of zipping in an ASP.Net environment with DotNetZip](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131216/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092910-1.aspx)